# No permission to remove file even after chmod 777

Tags: file-permissions

Here's what I did in putty. I have done chmod 777 to that file and I still can't remove it. Why?

```
[myuser@myapptest jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ ls -l README.txt
              -rwxrwxrwx. 1 myuser jboss 2421 Mar 10  2012 README.txt
[myuser@myapptest jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ rm README.txt
                 rm: cannot remove `README.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: may be it's in use (still open)?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, include in your question the permissions on the directory containing this file, hint hint.

Comment: Check permissions on the current directory, `ls -ld . README.txt` You will need write permission on the directory that contains your README